# Не работает выбор меткой bootstrap radio

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, input, checkbox

На примере [этой страницы](http://185.68.210.3/m-index.html#serverhosting/1):

В полноэкранном режиме метки ставятся, а если начать **менять размер окна - уже нет**.

Трабл в Хроме и Файрфоксе, в Эдж перестает работать с гораздо меньшего размера окна, в `Checkbox` метка тоже не ставится.

В чем может быть проблема? В Бутстрапе по меткам все стандартно:

```css
.radio + .radio, .checkbox + .checkbox {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" style="margin-left:1px">
<div class="radio col-xs-4"><label><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="Rack Unit, 1RU 300W, Price 45 &euro;">300W</label></div>
<div class="radio col-xs-4"><label><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="Rack Unit, 2RU 500W, Price 65 &euro;">500W</label></div>
<div class="radio col-xs-4"><label><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="Rack Unit, 3RU 750W, Price 95 &euro;">750W</label></div>
<div class="radio col-xs-4"><label><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="Rack Unit, 4RU 1kW, Price 125 &euro;">1kW</label></div>
<div class="radio col-xs-4"><label><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="Rack Unit, 5RU 1,25kW, Price 155 &euro;">1,25kW</label></div>
</div>
```

Comment: На уменьшенном экране на кликах по радио начинает работать какой-то JavaScript. При нажатиях он видимо отменяет действие выбора. Какой-то скрипт, что при клике по радио меняет стиль блока с классом fp-scroller

Comment: case 'click':
      if (this.enabled && !e._constructed) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
      }
      break; похоже вот это

Comment: @DmitryKozlov спасибо, вы оказались абсолютно правы! Какая польза от этого скрипта может быть вообще? Зачем автор сайта мог добавить его?

Comment: Видимо, как мне показалось, этот скрипт считает, что при уменьшении экрана работает только тачскрин, а не мышь